# Multiple Checkbox post

Tags: php, jquery

What is the best way to post muliple checkbox value and its siblings in jquery and get the post values in arrays by PHP?I have to get all values of checkbox and td.How can I do this?

Here is my checkbox in a table

```
<form action="test.php">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="A">1</td> <td>James</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="B">2</td> <td>Dave</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="C">3</td> <td>Bal</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="D">4</td> <td>Tim</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="E">5</td ><td>Ester</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I should get all post data of checkboxes like this inlcuding the td values.
    [event] => Array
        (
            [0] => array(A,James)
            [1] => array(B,Dave)
        )

Answer (score 2):

Just grab [all of the form data in one go](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
// …
data: jQuery('form').serialize()
// …
```

Reassociate the values with the labels (which should use proper `<label>` elements, you'll need to fix the HTML so the `id` attributes are *unique*) *on the server*.

Comment: How Can I grab the values of td's?

Comment: @mocca — Do that on the server. The server produced the HTML in the first place. It should do so using an array, a database, or some other system. Use the same set of data to associate them back. (Or use the data you are using for the labels for the values in the first place)

Comment: yes it can grab the checkbox values but it cannot post the TD innertext.

Comment: @mocca: ideally, you shouldn't be using a table for layout. I agree with Quentin's suggestion to use <label>. It's more accessible and semantic. Use CSS to align the fields rather than tables.

Comment: @mocca — Er, yes? As I said … twice … *do that on the server*.

Comment: the system is using tables by default.

Answer (score 0):

`name="event[VALUE]"`

That seems to be the easiest way to me. Alternatively, use a `<select multiple>` control.